# A localization helper in codeigniter

Tags: php, mvc, codeigniter, localization

I created a project to better understand CI3, while developing it I tried to introduce localization elements.
When I tried to localize the view everything messed up. I made a helper to identify if the user choose a language different than default language then load the right language.

```
function lang_load($lang_file)
{
    if($this->session->get_userdata('language'))
    {
        $this->lang->load($lang_file,$this->session->get_userdata('language'));
    }else
    {
        $this->lang->load($lang_file);
    }
}
```

so everytime instead use

```
$this->lang->load($lang_file);
```

I use

```
lang_load($lang_file)
```

I use it on Controllers and in the Views, but I guess it is breaking the MVC principle when used on view side.

Comment: This question resulted in this [commit](https://github.com/germanosk/frello/commit/75ba3328dc4e00b9e126a1afcc5215c16b16219f)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty trivial example for review, but you are right to question use of this function from within a view.

Personally I think this is information that needs to be determined upstream of this decision point, making the function unnecessary.

If you always used this format for loading language:

```
$this->lang->load($lang_file, $lang);
```

where `$lang` here could be a variable, constant, call to static class method, or some other way to get to the current language preference (with this preference determined somewhere outside the logic for actually loading the localization).